# How do fix this error "Null is not a subtype of type DocumentSnaphot<object?>

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am using the Streambuilder widget to build a real-time response screen. Everything works well. But when I navigate to the page from the particular complaints screen(the reason why the postId and postusername variables at the beginning) I get red error screen that disappears after a few seconds. This is the error I get "Another exception was thrown: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'"

```
class CommentsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  final String postusername;
  const CommentsScreen(
      {Key? key, required this.postId, required this.postusername})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CommentsScreenState createState() => _CommentsScreenState();
}

class _CommentsScreenState extends State<CommentsScreen> {
  final TextEditingController commentEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        title: const Text(
          'Responses',
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .doc(widget.postId)
            .collection('comments')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"));
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot answers = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                DateTime postDate = answers['datePublished'].toDate();
                String formattedDate =
                    DateFormat.yMMMd().add_jm().format(postDate);
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(primaryPadding),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 15,
                    shadowColor: secondaryColor,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(primaryPadding),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
                                radius: 18,
                                child: Text(
                                  answers['username'][0],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: primaryColor,
                                      fontSize: fontSizeFive),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(answers['username'],
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: fontSizeFour,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                                  Text(formattedDate,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: fontSizeTwo,
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Divider(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            answers['answers'],
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: fontSizeThree),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        },
      ),
      // text input
      bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data;
              String pic = user['photoUrl'];

              return Container(
                height: kToolbarHeight,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 8),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(pic),
                      radius: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 16, right: 8, bottom: 10),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: commentEditingController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(circularRadius))),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried a few options like playing around will the null check operators but nothing seems to sort this issue. Any help, please?
below is how my terminal looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the error? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Check this line: "DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data;" and provide a value if null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the snapshot has error or has data before trying to get the data. In this example, I display error message if the snapshot has error and I display circular progress indicator if snapshot does not have data. I only display the Container if it passes both of these check.

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"));
      }
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
    }
    DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data;
    String pic = user['photoUrl'];

     return Container(
```

Comment: I added the code block to check if it has data and if the data has an error but it still gives me the same bug.

Comment: Can you try `DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data ?? [];`